Sum of sine should give cotangent
I have the following sum, of which I would like to find a closed form:
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)$$
Wolfram alpha hints me that this sum is equal to $\cot(\pi/(2N))$ for $N \ge 2$.
However my steps here are the following:
$$ \frac{1}{2i} \sum_{k = 0}^{N - 1} e^{i\pi k/N} - e^{-i\pi k/N} = \frac{1}{2i} \left[ \frac{2}{1 - e^{i\pi/N}} - \frac{2}{1 - e^{-i\pi/N}} \right] = \frac{1}{i} \left[ \frac{1 - e^{i\pi/N} - (1 - e^{-i\pi/N})}{|1 - e^{i\pi/N}|} \right] = \frac{1}{i} \left[ \frac{e^{-i\pi/N} - e^{i\pi/N}}{|1 - e^{i\pi/N}|} \right]$$
While I see that the denominator is $\sin(\pi/2N)$ as expected, I don't see how the rest becomes $\cos(\pi/2N)$. I can't see any mistakes.

For what it's worth, I have noticed that a common trick in these kinds of problems is to employ the strategy used in the answer of Surb.  That is, extend the expression to be evaluated into an expression that directly involves something like a series involving $~e^{i\theta}~$ and then reason that you want either the purely real portion or the purely imaginary portion of the resulting computation.  This approach seems to make such problems easier to attack.

@user2661923 you're right. I usually decompose sines and cosines blindly, and this allows me to do it more "mechanically", but I see that, as in this case, it is quite error-prone.

The wrong thing in your calculation is that you used $z\bar z=|z|$ whereas $z\bar z=|z|^2.$

Using my previous remark should allows you to solve your problem. However, I would do a bit differently :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{i\pi k/N}=\frac{2}{1-e^{i\pi /N}}=\frac{2e^{-i\pi/2N}}{e^{-i\pi/2N}-e^{i\pi/2N}}=-\frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{-i\pi/2N}}{\sin(\pi/2N)}=1+i\frac{\cos(\pi/2N)}{\sin(\pi/2n)}.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sin(k\pi/N)=\Im\left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{i\pi k/N}\right)=\frac{\cos(\pi/2N)}{\sin(\pi/2N)}=\cot(\pi/2N).$$

Ahh, stupid mistake, thanks :) also for the cleaner proof!
